# How to set TAG when sending data from Kafka to Influxdb

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using [Confluent Influxdb Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-influxdb/) to send data to Influxdb from Kafka. The configuration looks like this:

```
connector.class=io.confluent.influxdb.InfluxDBSinkConnector
influxdb.url=myurl
topics=mytopic
tasks.max=1
```

The schema looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "myrecord",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "sn",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "value",
      "type": "float"
    },
    {
      "name": "tagnum",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

When sending the data from Kafka to Influxdb, every data item was regarded as FIELD.

How to set some of the data items as TAG when sent to InfluxDB from Kafka by using the InfluxDB Connector, such as set "tagnum" as TAG ?

Answer (score 0):

Your schema would look like this. The important thing is that your tags are in a `map` field.

```js
{
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
        { "type": "map", "keys": { "type": "string", "optional": false }, "values": { "type": "string", "optional": false }, "optional": false, "field": "tags" },
        { "field": "sn", "optional": false, "type": "string" },
        { "field": "value", "optional": false, "type": "float" }
    ],
    "optional": false,
    "version": 1
}
```

Here's an example sending a JSON payload:

```sh
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -P -t testdata-json4 <<EOF
{ "schema": { "type": "struct", "fields": [ { "type": "map", "keys": { "type": "string", "optional": false }, "values": { "type": "string", "optional": false }, "optional": false, "field": "tags" }, { "field": "sn", "optional": false, "type": "string" }, { "field": "value", "optional": false, "type": "float" } ], "optional": false, "version": 1 }, "payload": { "tags": { "tagnum": "5" }, "sn": "FOO", "value": 500.0 } }
EOF

curl -i -X PUT -H "Accept:application/json" \
        -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/SINK_INFLUX_01/config \
        -d '{
            "connector.class"               : "io.confluent.influxdb.InfluxDBSinkConnector",
            "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
            "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
            "key.converter"                 : "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
            "topics"                        : "testdata-json4",
            "influxdb.url"                  : "http://influxdb:8086",
            "influxdb.db"                   : "my_db",
            "measurement.name.format"       : "${topic}"
        }'
```

The result in InfluxDB:

```sql
$ influx -execute 'SELECT * FROM "testdata-json4" GROUP BY tagnum;' -database "my_db"

name: testdata-json4
tags: tagnum=5
time                sn  value
----                --  -----
1579713749737000000 FOO 500
```

Ref: https://rmoff.net/2020/01/23/notes-on-getting-data-into-influxdb-from-kafka-with-kafka-connect/